# Ошибка Angular в mean.io при сборке

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, angular

Скачал последнюю версию mean.io с помощью Git,

```
git clone https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git
cd mean
npm install && npm start
```

Сделал все по инструкции, но Angular не может начинать собирать и выдает такие ошибки

```
[SERVER] [nodemon] 1.17.5
[SERVER] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[SERVER] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[SERVER] [nodemon] starting `node server`
[SERVER] ../../dist/
[SERVER] server started on port 4040 (development)
[BUILD] Date: 2018-09-30T09:57:22.769Z
[BUILD] Hash: 6d57f96de878cdaa4003
[BUILD] Time: 4867ms
[BUILD] chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 611 bytes [initial] [rendered]
[BUILD] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 666 bytes [initial] [rendered]
[BUILD] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
[BUILD] chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 102 kB [initial] [rendered]
[BUILD]
[BUILD] ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(72,67): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
[BUILD] node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[BUILD] node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[BUILD] node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(74,39): error TS1109: Expression expected.
[BUILD] node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(79,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[BUILD] node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/extended/typings/style/style.d.ts(80,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

Пробовал повышать версию Typescript до 2.9.2, но в таком случае Angular пишет что требуется версия ниже

Comment: какая версия flex-layout и rxjs?

Comment: "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.16",
"rxjs": "6.2.0"

Comment: спасибо! все работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что только `TypeScript >= 2.9.2` разрешает использовать ключевое слово `import` в объявлениях типов. Также компилятор Angular ругается, потому что использует версию `< 2.8.0`. Для поддержки `TypeScript >= 2.9.2` нам нужна версия компилятора `>= 6.1.1`. Для этого в IDE в файле `package.json` меняем `6.0.3` на `6.1.1`. Версию `TypeScript` меняем на `"typescript": "2.9.2"`. Также версию `angular-cli` меняем на `"@angular/cli": "6.1.1"`, чтобы не было ворнингов и делаем `npm install` (используйте `yarn`).